# Extract dictionary from QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, dictionary, qtreewidget

I already managed to properly create this treewidget from a dictionary, but now I want to reverse engineer it, and I want to create a dictionary from this qtreewidget. 
I am quite lost on how to do that, it seems straight forward but I fail.

The idea is to get the parent items

```
for index in range(self.treeWidget.topLevelItemCount()):
        parent = self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(index)
```

from there on I need to recursively go through each sublevel with parent.childCount(), if childCount is valid, then iterate over child.

But I dont know how to create a dictionary from that. 
Please someone help me out..
Ideally I get something like this

```
"core.global_vars.arrunner_qmenu_object_name"
"core.global_vars.metadata_label"
"core.logger.console_verbosity"
```

Or in the best case `{"core:{"global_vars:{"arrunner_qmenu_object_name":None}}, ...}`

[image]

**UPDATE**

replaceJson is the main functions which gets the root parents,
from there on I gather all the childrens and add them to global children list. 
After that, I generate a string from that "root.child.child.child" which I can expand to a dict `{"root":"{"child":...}}`

Then back in replace Json I add the string to the config..
There is probably a way easier way..
Any help is appreciated.

so this is what I came up with:

```
def children(self, parent):
    global children
    childCount = parent.childCount()
    if childCount:
        for index in range(childCount):
            self.children(parent.child(index))
    elif not parent.parent() and not parent.text(1):  # top levels without children
        children.append(parent)
    if parent.text(1):
        children.append(parent)

def generateString(self, treeItem):
    def getParent(item):
        if item.parent():
            global parents
            parents.append(str(item.parent().text(0)))
            getParent(item.parent())
    global parents
    parents = [str(treeItem.text(0))]
    getParent(treeItem)
    attribute, value = '.'.join(parents[::-1]), treeItem.text(1)
    return attribute, value

def _replaceJson(self):
    super(JsonEditor, self)._replaceJson()
    writeToFile(self.configFile, "{}")
    # Getting children
    global children
    children = []
    for index in range(self.treeWidget.topLevelItemCount()):
        parent = self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(index)
        self.children(parent)
    # Generating config string
    for child in children:
        attribute, value = self.generateString(child)
        self._addToConfig(attribute, value)
    self.log.info("Updated config file: {}".format(os.path.basename(self.configFile)))
    self.close()
```

Comment: You are in the right track. Iterate over the children and then you can get the content with `children.text(column_number)`. Then you can build the string or the dictionary.

Comment: I already got the text from the column. What my problem is when I do it recursively, I don't know how to append the top most parent with all the sublevels to generate the dictionary. I can always get parent and child but not parent.child.subchild.subbchild etc.

Comment: So please add the code that you've got so far, including the recursive part and the results you have achieved (even if they're wrong).